# Add Hash Values in nested hash - Join Nested Hashes Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, merge, nested

I have two hashes..

```
[
    {
        "title"=>"CEO",
        "name"=>"George",
        "columns"=>[
      {
        "display_name"=> "Salary",
        "value"=>"3.85",
      }
    , {
        "display_name"=> "Bonus",
        "value"=>"994.19",
      }
    , {
        "display_name"=> "Increment",
        "value"=>"8.15",
       }
                    ]
    }
]


data2 = JSON.parse(data2)['info']
puts data2

[
    {
        "title"=>"CEO",
        "name"=>"George",
        "columns"=>[
      {
        "display_name"=> "Address",
        "value"=>"Albany",
      }
    , {
        "display_name"=> "Phone",
        "value"=>"47123",
      }
    , {
        "display_name"=> "Mobile",
        "value"=>"784123",
      }
                    ]
    }
]
```

I want to join the values inside "columns" into one hash if the conditions are met like name = george in both hashes

the required output to be like

```
[
    {
        "title"=>"CEO",
        "name"=>"George",
        "columns"=>[
      {
        "display_name"=> "Salary",
        "value"=>"3.85",
      }
    , {
        "display_name"=> "Bonus",
        "value"=>"994.19",
      }
    , {
        "display_name"=> "Increment",
        "value"=>"8.15",
      }
    , {
        "display_name"=> "Address",
        "value"=>"Albany",
      }
    , {
        "display_name"=> "Phone",
        "value"=>"47123",
      }
    , {
        "display_name"=> "Mobile",
        "value"=>"784123",
      }
                      ]
    }
]
```

What I have tried is zip, merge, inject, join, hash deep merge, but the best I can get is a new Hash that discards all first values and store second

Comment: I would say you need an identifier for each of your records to compare them when merging.

Comment: "name"=>"George" - could be the identifier?? or matcher - id name in both is same then dump value of columns into first hash...

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`Array#|`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C) to merge both arrays:

```
data.each do |item|
    # find matching entry in data2
    item2 = data2.find {|item2| item2['name'] == item['name'] }
    # join both columns if matching data was found
    item['columns'] = item['columns'] | item2['columns'] if item2
end
```

This modifies your `data` variable to contain the columns of both `data` and `data2`.

```
=> [{"title"=>"CEO",
  "name"=>"George",
  "columns"=>
   [{"display_name"=>"Salary", "value"=>"3.85"},
    {"display_name"=>"Bonus", "value"=>"994.19"},
    {"display_name"=>"Increment", "value"=>"8.15"},
    {"display_name"=>"Address", "value"=>"Albany"},
    {"display_name"=>"Phone", "value"=>"47123"},
    {"display_name"=>"Mobile", "value"=>"784123"}]}]
```

The block in `item2 = data2.find {|item2| item2['name'] == item['name'] }` defines whether two items are equal or not. You may modify that block to also compare other values (e.g. `title`) if you like.

---

For the record this is how I think `data` and `data2` are defined:

```
data= [
    {"title"=>"CEO",
    "name"=>"George",
    "columns"=>[
        {
            "display_name"=> "Salary",
            "value"=>"3.85",
        }, {
            "display_name"=> "Bonus",
            "value"=>"994.19",
        }, {
            "display_name"=> "Increment",
            "value"=>"8.15",
        }
    ]}
  ]

data2 = [{
    "title"=>"CEO",
    "name"=>"George",
    "columns"=>[{
        "display_name"=> "Address",
        "value"=>"Albany",
    }, {
        "display_name"=> "Phone",
        "value"=>"47123",
    }, {
        "display_name"=> "Mobile",
        "value"=>"784123",
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...Does ur output have the initial title, name etc... seems to be missing...

Comment: Where do you expect `title`, `name` etc. to be? These associations are still present in the original `data` array.

Comment: You should run the whole thing, beginning with `data.each` until the `end`. The assignment you cited returns only the column hash, but it modifies the `data` variable as you wish.

Comment: To Save into CSV in a single line this works...


    File.open("data.csv", "w") {|f| f.write(data.inject([]) { |csv, row|  csv << CSV.generate_line(row) }.join(""))}